# Why do the police use "K-9" or "K-9 Unit" instead of "dog"?

Tags: terminology, abbreviations, legalese, origin-unknown, animals

Throughout North America, I keep seeing police cars labeled "[K-9 unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_dog)". I know "K-9" is a homophone of "canine", but why don't they just use "police dog"?

> A police dog, also known as K-9 or K9 (a homophone of canine), is a dog specifically trained to assist members of law enforcement. - [*nationalpolicedogfoundation.org*](https://www.nationalpolicedogfoundation.org/about-k9s)

Comment: You have to use *something*. You could say "police dog", or you could say "canine unit", or you could say "doggy-doggy goo-goo", or a million other things, and so can everyone else, and then we all have to agree on which term is the universally accepted one. That is just how language works. If they used "police dog", you'd be asking the exact opposite question now. You have to use *some* term that works, and "canine unit" *is* a term that works, and that is all there is to it.

Comment: Plus I think it's shorter and more readily comprehended when printed in large letters on the sides of police vehicles.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: huh? By that logic we should be using the weirdest synonyms instead of common words all the time. Have I asked why a "dog" is a man's best friend, and not a "K-9 unit"? No.

Comment: What is behind the question, and what the question does not fully spell out is that *K-9* seems to be deliberately obfuscating. Somebody who sees K-9 for the first time is bound to wonder what it means and to presume that there is also K-1, K-2 . . . K-8.

Comment: Plus it's cute. Or considered to be cute, which is the same thing.

Comment: @JohnLawler That is the answer - it is good PR.

Answer (score 7):

***Origin of the term 'K-9 unit'***

An Elephind newspaper database search turns up at least one instance of "K-9 unit" from World War II. From "[5th Infantry Dog Up to Snuff With '201' File](https://www.coloradohistoricnewspapers.org/cgi-bin/colorado?a=d&d=CCM19431111-01.2.5&e=-------en-20--1--img-txIN%7ctxCO%7ctxTA-%22K%252D9+unit%22-------0--)" in the *[Colorado Springs, Colorado] Camp Carson Mountaineer* (November 11, 1943):

> It is not unusual for a soldier to have a personal (201) file in Regimental Headquarters. This is standard operating procedure. Not is it news when a dog bites a man. Bu this is a case where the dog involved did not bite anyone—but has a file (201) all his own.
>
> The canine in question answers to the name of Charley. He is owned and operated by the Regimental Adjutant, Capt. Adelbert Boggs. Charley i a fine, year-old Doberman Pinscher. He joined the Regiment way down yonder at Camp Van Dorn.
>
> The file keeper, S/Sgt. Saul Kash is in charge of Charley's 201 file as well as those of the entire Regiment. He says that Charley's dossier is quite complete. It contains Charley's admittance date to the Fifth—and very valuable documents surrounding the pup's efforts to join the fighting **K-9 unit**. This, as you know is the corps of trained dogs which is proving of such invaluable assistance to our sentries everywhere.

Newspaper references to "K-9 corps" during the same year are far more numerous, however. Here are the earliest three such instances. From "[Two Coronado Dogs Accepted by Army's 'Dogs for Defense'](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=CJ19430107.2.4&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522K%252D9+corps%252522-------1)," in the *Coronado [California] Journal* (January 7. 1943):

> Forty-one San Diego county dogs to date have been accepted for service in the new **K-9 corps** of the United States Army, it was announced by officials of Dogs for Denfense, Inc., in charge of recruiting of the canine-soldiers in San Diego and Imperial counties.

"Denfense" appears to be a typo, but with stories like this one, you never know.

From "[Falla's a Private](https://news.hrvh.org/veridian/cgi-bin/senylrc?a=d&d=idadcaae19430309.1.21&txq=%22K-9+corps%22)," in the *[Newburgh, New York] Stewart Field United States Military Academy Prop Wash* (March 9, 1943):

> Falla, President Roosevelt’s Scottish terrier, has gone to war. He hasn’t joined the **K-9 Corps**, for he isn’t big enough. But he’s a private, thanks to the President’s personal $1 donation to the War Dog Fund. The dollar entitled Falla to the rank of either an Army private or a Navy seaman, and the President asked that Falla be made a private. War Dog Fund has turned over $15,000 so far to Dogs for Defense, national procurement agency of dogs being used by the various military services at home and abroad.

From an [untitled item](https://digmichnews.cmich.edu/cgi-bin/michigan?a=d&d=LeelanauSBC19430408-01.1.1&txq=%22K-9+corps%22) in the *Suttons Bay [Michigan] Courier* (April 8, 1943):

> They’re in the army now—bow wow, and how! Tens of thousands of America’s dags have gone to war, in the **K-9 corps**. Read of the splendid job they’re doing and how they’re trained, as told by Louis de Casanova, former editor of the Kennel Club Gazette, in The American Weekly, the magazine distributed with next week's Chicago Herald-American.

None of these early instances explains the origin of the name—but presumably that's because it was obviously chosen as a visual pun—making the verbal connection between the word *canine* and the military inclination to organize individuals (whether people or dogs) into groups with numerical IDs. The fact that "K-9 corps" and "K-9 unit" were appearing in newspapers across the country—from New York to Michigan to Colorado to California (along with instances in newspapers from Indiana, Texas, Virginia, and Hawaii)—within the year 1943 indicates that the name caught the fancy of working journalists (and evidently the U.S. public as well). I didn't find any mentions of "K-9 unit" or "K-9 corps" in the Elephind database from 1942 or earlier.

---

***Man-dog team or police department subunit?***

It seems worth noting that "K-9 unit"—like "K-9 corps"—originally applied to a section or group of trained military dogs, not to a particular pairing of a dog and its handler. In modern policing, however, people sometimes apply the the term "K-9 unit" to a man-dog team and sometimes to the unit of the police force that consists of such teams. Thus, for example, from "[Local Man Fires Shot at Burglars, Suspects Escape Police Dragnet](https://www.coloradohistoricnewspapers.org/cgi-bin/colorado?a=d&d=LVT19901205-01.2.4&e=-------en-20--1--img-txIN%7ctxCO%7ctxTA-%22K%252D9+unit%22-------0--)," in the Louisville, Colorado Times (December 5, 1990, page 11) we have an instance of the "man-dag team" sense of the term:

> Louisville police also requested a **K-9 unit** from the Boulder County Sheriffs Office, but no dog units were available for the search. Somehow the two young burglars managed to elude the dragnet. Glass said their escape was especially frustrating, as they may be linked to burglaries in Broomfield and Longmont.

But far more common in Elephind's newspaper matches is the term in its departmental sense, as in this instance from Shawn Dockry, "[Kent Police Praise Dog Unit](https://dks.library.kent.edu/cgi-bin/kentstate?a=d&d=dks19910405-01.2.29&txq=%22K-9+unit%22)," in the *[Kent, Ohio] Daily Kent Stater* (April 5, 1991):

> The Kent City Police and the Portage County Sheriffs departments literally want to take a bite out of crime with their respective **K-9 units**.
>
> Portage County Sheriff P. Ken Howe said his **dog unit** started six months ago with one dog, Erd, pronounced 'Ed.' A new dog was added to the unit in March.
>
> "The dogs are to us what the horses are to Cleveland (police units)," Howe said.
>
> The creation of the **K-9 unit** was a campaign promise of 1988, Howe said. The dogs are used to track lost people and suspects, to sniff out drugs and to back up officers.

Comment: Normally, we don't expect an **official** name of something within a government entity to be a pun. While it is not too difficult to understand how some people may have started using *K-9* among themselves as an in-joke, it still remains puzzling how it could have become a term that is widely used in formal, official contexts.

Comment: @jsw29: On the other hand, the U.S. military seems to have gone to great lengths in 1942 to construct a cute ocean-appropriate acronym for women serving as auxiliaries in the U.S. Navy (the naval analogue to the Women's Army Corps). The simple, logical name would have been "Women's Naval Corps," but the official one that the government actually adopted was "Women Accepted for Voluntary Emergency Service" ("WAVES").

Comment: True, but *WAVES* is quite different from *K-9*, because everybody who sees *WAVES* will immediately know that it is an acronym, and that to understand it, one needs to find what it is the acronym for. On the other hand somebody who sees *K-9 unit* for the first time, will assume that it stands for the ninth among K units; it is unlikely to immediately occur to one to look for a word that is pronounced similarly to *K-9*. It takes a while to 'get' the joke, because one doesn't expect that kind of a joke in such a context.

Answer (score 5):

The term appears to originate from the term "K-9 Corps", being a shorthand for the Army's War Dog Program [established during World War II](http://www.47ipsd.us/47k9hist.htm). (http://www.qmfound.com/K-9.htm).

Also, "K-9 Unit" is often used to refer to both the police dog as well as its handler. So a simple replacement with "police dog" would be insufficient.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but merely moves it one step back: why were the K-9 Corps of the Army's War Dog Program so called?

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough, there is an early sci-fi movie called [Just Imagine](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0021016/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0) that was released in 1930. It depicts the future of New York City in 1980 where humans are referred to by numbers. The dog is referred to as K9 even with a tag on it that reads K9. I wonder if this is where it all started.

Comment: Is it a police dog?

Comment: @livresque I don't see why it would need to be a police dog for this to be a reasonable source. Domestic dogs, sheepdogs and police dogs are all canines. Given that Just Imagine came out in 1930 it could easily, if sufficiently popular, have influenced the naming of the WWII canine units. I assume that Dr Who's robotic assistant was named after the US army or police units, I'd never seen the pun before that in the UK.

Comment: @BoldBen It is good information, just hoping for more.   If only the question were for earliest use of the term/pun instead of why.  If it were a police dog in the movie, that should be included.  For example, the TARDIS does look like an old police call box lately.

Answer (score 2):

The origin of the term *K-9* goes back as early as 1857; and it was first used as a number assigned for a stray dog, per *[Green's Slang Dictionary](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/ktc2eda)*.

> **1.** a dog.
>
> Sergeant Watkinson, K 9 (certainly a most appropriate number) deposed to having discovered the stray pet [...] and then and there, spite of the dog’s animosity to all police [...] captured the brute. 
> <sub>*Bell’s Life in Sydney* 2 May 3/4</sub>

---

Update: In the above citation, I've originally thought the number *K 9* was also assigned to the stray dog by the sergeant because *K 9* sounds like *canine* and GDoS provides the citation under the meaning "a dog". Sven Yargs has found additional valuable information from Australian archive below where it is mentioned that *K 9* is the badge number of the sergeant; and the original usage of *K 9* is connected to the police department and the dog indirectly:

> It appears from "[Police Pickings](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/59866479?searchTerm=%22Sergeant%20Watkinson%22)" in *Bell's Life in Sydney*, and *Sporting Reviewer* (May 2, 1857) that "K 9" is the sergeant's badge number, although the reporter makes the humorous connection: "K 9 [Watkinson], of course, knew nothing about such vermin, not he—he wasn't a dog fancier—not he; his letter and number did not quality him as such, though it did read canine." Sergeant Watkinson appears in multiple Sydney newspaper articles from 1855 to 1857, but never again as "K 9."

---

After that, the term was adopted by U.S Army first for the [War Dog Program (K-9 Corps)](https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/u-s-army-launches-k-9-corps) during World War II and then it was adopted for the police dogs.

From 2000, the term has the sense 'a corrections officer' also, per *Green's Slang Dictionary*:

> K-9 Corrections officer (canine). 
> <sub>*Other Side of the Wall: Prisoner’s Dict.* July</sub>

---

<sub>Further read for the history of K9 breeds: 

*[K9 Working Breeds: Characteristics and Capabilities](https://books.google.es/books/about/K9_Working_Breeds.html?id=ofUOAQAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y)* By Resi Gerritsen, Ruud Haak</sub>

Comment: How is the *Bell's Life* citation relevant here? If I've understood it right, "K 9" applies to the sergeant, and the dog is not a police dog.

Comment: @SvenYargs Thank you for the valuable information and the resource of Australian archive! I've updated my answer and credited you.

Answer (score 1):

1) "K-9" or "K9" -- a typographic pun upon "canine", inherited from military jargon. They could have said canine, or dog (though someone would surely then complain that they weren't giving bitches equal credit). Someone just happened to like this bit of jargon, and it stuck.

2) "K9 Unit" -- The "unit" isn't just the animal, but the team of the animal and its handler.

(The term sometimes also includes the vehicle, when it has been specially modified for this purpose. For example, the local K-9 units have the handler carry a transmitter which can remotely release the dog from their van. They do "live training" demos of this at some of the local fairs, showing how quickly the dog can be out of the van and assisting. I'm not sure whether the transmitter has a deadman/man-down sensor or if the officer has to explicitly press a button; if I was designing it, it would support both modes.)

Answer (score 0):

Additional: in the UK police, K9 unit dogs all have an official police rank: PD (police dog). The handler gives evidence in court, something like "We gave chase, and PD Rover apprehended the suspect."  PDs don't officially  make an arrest because they cant read the suspect his/her rights!

Comment: This goes along with _PC_ for Police Constable. Who can forget "PC 31 says we got a dirty one"?